# Writing class objects as multi-lined strings

Tags: python, string, class, object

I have a code in Python:

```
class House:
    def __init__(self, Address, Bedrooms, Bathrooms, Garage, Price):
        self.Address= Address
        self.Price = Price
        self.Bathrooms= Bathrooms
        self.Garage= Garage
        if Garage == 1:
            x="Attached garage"
        else:
            x="No Garage"
     
    def getPrice(self):
         return self.price

h1 = House("1313 Mockingbird Lane", 3, 2.5, True, 300000)        
h2 = House("0001 Cemetery Lane", 4, 1.75, False, 400000)
```

now if I type `print(h1)` I want all the object to be shown as a multi-lined string. For Example:
`print(h1)` gives

```
1313 Mockingbird Lane
Bedrooms: 3 Bathrooms: 2.5
Attached garage
Price: 300000
```

Comment: You have to implement a `__str__(self)` method in your class returning a multi-line string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a lot of the 'boiler plate' code from your example by using dataclasses

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class House:
    Address: str
    Bedrooms: int
    Bathrooms: int
    Garage: bool
    Price: float
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f"""{self.Address}
Bedrooms: {self.Bedrooms} Bathrooms: {self.Bathrooms}
Garage: {self.Garage}
Price: {self.Price}"""

h1 = House("1313 Mockingbird Lane", 3, 2.5, True, 300000)        
h2 = House("0001 Cemetery Lane", 4, 1.75, False, 400000)

print(h1)
print(h2)
```

The dataclass decorator will automatically create the init function for your class.

Comment: Thanks, I just added an if loop for the garage and now I'm all set to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
class House:
    def __init__(self, Address, Bedrooms, Bathrooms, Garage, Price):
        self.Address= Address
        self.Price = Price
        self.Bathrooms= Bathrooms
        self.Garage= Garage
        if Garage == 1:
            x="Attached garage"
        else:
            x="No Garage"
     
    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(f"{key} : {val}" for key, val in self.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith('_'))

    def getPrice(self):
         return self.price



h1 = House("1313 Mockingbird Lane", 3, 2.5, True, 300000)        
h2 = House("0001 Cemetery Lane", 4, 1.75, False, 400000)
print(h1)
```

Gives you this :

```
Address : 1313 Mockingbird Lane
Price : 300000
Bathrooms : 2.5
Garage : True
```

Comment: Thanks, now I jus have to find a way to print "Attached garage" and "No garage"